# Ping stops responding after the first line

Tags: windows, networking, command-line-interface, ping, windows-8

I have a problem with the `PING` command on Windows 8.1. During a ping, the command returns no further output after sending the first ping request.

For example:

```
ping 192.168.1.200

Pinging 192.168.1.200 with 32 bytes of data
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT 1:**

I did a test with Wireshark to see what happens. 
[Here is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o7Zg.jpg)
I've tried many things, but nothing has helped.

If you have any ideas ...

**EDIT 2 :**

I've added the result of `ipconfig /all`

```
Configuration IP de Windows

   Nom de l'hôte . . . . . . . . . . : NEPTUNE
   Suffixe DNS principal . . . . . . : xxx.xxxx.fr
   Type de noeud. . . . . . . . . .  : Hybride
   Routage IP activé . . . . . . . . : Non
   Proxy WINS activé . . . . . . . . : Non
   Liste de recherche du suffixe DNS.: xxx.xxxx.fr

Carte Ethernet vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal
 Switch) :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Carte Ethernet virtuelle Hyper-V #2
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-29-83-27
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Non
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::64dd:8e3:4166:be79%19(préféré)

   Adresse d'autoconfiguration IPv4 . . . : 169.254.190.121(préféré)
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . :
   IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 318772573
   DUID de client DHCPv6. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-07-94-FD-50-E5-49-3A-9A
-48
   Serveurs DNS. . .  . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS sur Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . : Activé

Carte Ethernet Connexion au réseau local :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Contrôleur Realtek PCIe GBE Family
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 50-E5-49-3A-9A-48
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Non
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.1.5(préféré)
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   Serveurs DNS. . .  . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                   8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS sur Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . : Activé
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your example doesn't show anything useful. Can you alaborate on your question? Do you mean that the ping target doesn't respond?

Comment: My target responds from another pc. The target can be anything the command "ping" always crashes after the first line. My firewall is off.

Comment: Sounds like Windows might be corrupted. Have you run `sfc /scannow` yet?

Comment: Can you ping yourself? (e. g.  **ping 127.0.0.1**). If not, you've got problems on your machine with the TCP/IP stack.

Comment: Let's try to isolate the issue then. Plug in a laptop into your ethernet port and see if you can ping, if not, network; if so, then it's probably your OS or NIC. Maybe safe-mode with networking is in order?

Comment: Some questions: can you give the contents of your routing table (route print -4), also can you display a wireshark trace of the ping without the filter (i want to see dns requests)

Comment: This usually also causes `tracert` to fail if someone did wonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears that you can't ping your own computer, the problem seems to be purely software, as the loopback interface is not passing through your network card. Either Windows has a corrupted TCP/IP stack or configuration for some reason, or something is preventing TCP/IP from correctly working (this can be a legitimate software, like an anti-virus, that for some reason is not working as it should, or it can be a malware that has severe side-effects).

You can perhaps try to [reinitialize your TCP/IP stack as shown here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-reset-tcp-ip-by-using-the-netshell-utility-d954430c-9b11-43f0-6081-0fc9235a8b4a). If still not successful, you might have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: AAfter testing this patch microsoft, I decided to reinstall. 
So after reinstalling everything works again thank you.

Comment: @KevinPoirier ok, cool that the problem is solved!

Comment: I edited the post because the link was deprecated. The current alternative I found is [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299357) which resolves to [the link I inserted](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-reset-tcp-ip-by-using-the-netshell-utility-d954430c-9b11-43f0-6081-0fc9235a8b4a). Alternatively, you can also use the wayback machine to see a [snapshot from when the site still worked](http://web.archive.org/web/20150103204025/http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/299357). This snapshot actually looks a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some kind of firewall installed on your system, that blocks the outgoing icmp packet.

Comment: I no have  firewall. In my screen capture wireshark, we notice that I get the ping response.

Comment: These Destination unreachable ICMP messages to you are sending to Googles DNS server look very strange to me.

Are you using Googles DNS Server? What does ipconfig /all show?

Comment: Yes i use google dns. I add ipconfig on my first post.

Comment: Maybe you have some problem with reverse DNS. Could you try a different DNS server?

Comment: I do not think the problem comes from the dns. Ping reacts like if I test a local IP address.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to faulty hardware, such as a bad NIC. Ive seen a report where replacing a router alleviated this type of issue, but the fact that other computers can ping, eliminates this culprit... Or have you attempted to ping using an alternate user profile on the computer?

Comment: I tested another profile still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen strange things happen when ICS [(Internet Connection Sharing)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7) is enabled.

Perhaps it's worth verifying if it's enabled.  If it is, try disabling it and then seeing if that helps your problem.  It's helped me in the past with funky issues with VM's and vpn connections.

Answer (score 0):

Ping command sends ICMP packets and waits for an answer; ICMP packets can be blocked locally by your software firewall or at ANY gateway in the middle of the route.

Try tracing a route first:

```
tracert -d google.fr
```

This will give you a list of jumps. Send a ping to each one of these servers to find out which one is preventing you from pinging outside.

**Reminder:** I cant stress this enough, any firewall/router could be blocking ping requests to the outside, this could be your ISP, university, home router, etc.

**Edit**: I asume you can ping your own computer...

```
ping localhost
ping 127.0.0.1
```

If you can't ping your own computer then we can try something else, this step must be cleared first.

Comment: I cannot ping my computer. Same problem.

Comment: I would start by reinstalling your network card drivers, if you have a faulty hardware it wont ONLY fail at ping. This is a software problem.


Beign said that, if your drivers are ok then open services.msc and restart the "server" service as well as the rest of the network services... one of them could be originating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it likely that you're falling foul of ICMP rate limiting on some firewall (perhaps the target host). If you ping with a (perhaps) much longer interval, it may work.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling IPv6 and enabling IPv4 on the vEthernet adaptor. If still not working, under Advanced set your metric to 1.

---

**Further troubleshooting**

Does pinging an IPv6 address give you the same results?

Disable the "Carte Ethernet vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)" adaptor (Run ncpa.cpl, right click) and try an IPv4 ping again. If you can ping correctly, it's probably the configuration in your vEthernet adaptor. Re-enable the adaptor.

You definitely have a DNS resolution problem according to wireshark (see http://www.wildpackets.com/resources/compendium/tcp_ip/unreachable for descriptions on the errors), and your virtual switch only has default IPv6 DNS servers and your physical adaptor only has google IPv4 DNS servers. Do you still get the same behaviour when DNS is working correctly?

Also, doesn't hurt to know what is in your hosts file - %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Answer (score 0):

Your packet trace reveals a bug in the IP stack on `192.168.1.5`.

The communication in summary:

- `192.168.1.5` -> `173.194.45.47` ICMP echo request
- `173.194.45.47` -> `192.168.1.5` ICMP echo reply
- `192.168.1.5` -> `173.194.45.47` ICMP error: I don't support ICMP

This is not standards compliant. First of all ICMP is a mandatory part of IP, so not supporting ICMP is not valid. Secondly it makes no sense to be sending ICMP packets and simultaneously saying you do not support ICMP.

This sort of broken IP stack is usually caused by a firewall. Assuming the trace was produced on `192.168.1.5` itself (which seems like the case based on timing of the packets), then the broken firewall must also be on `192.168.1.5`.